# TSQL - Populating values above and below an entry by referencing other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table which looks like:

[image]

This can be recreated from the code below:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.EmpnoProblem
(
DATE date NULL,
WORKNO nvarchar(50) NULL,
OPSEQ int NULL,
RELEASED nchar(10) NULL,
PRODUCT nvarchar(50) NULL,
EMPNO nvarchar(50) NULL
) ;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmpnoProblem] (DATE, WORKNO, OPSEQ, RELEASED, PRODUCT, EMPNO)
VALUES ('2016-06-16', '12345', 10, '10', '5454ABC', NULL);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmpnoProblem] (DATE, WORKNO, OPSEQ, RELEASED, PRODUCT, EMPNO)
VALUES ('2016-06-16', '12345', 20, '10', '5454ABC', NULL);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmpnoProblem] (DATE, WORKNO, OPSEQ, RELEASED, PRODUCT, EMPNO)
VALUES ('2016-06-16', '12345', 30, '10', '5454ABC', '345');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmpnoProblem] (DATE, WORKNO, OPSEQ, RELEASED, PRODUCT, EMPNO)
VALUES ('2016-06-16', '12345', 40, '10', '5454ABC', '345');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmpnoProblem] (DATE, WORKNO, OPSEQ, RELEASED, PRODUCT, EMPNO)
VALUES ('2016-06-16', '12345', 50, '10', '5454ABC', NULL);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmpnoProblem] (DATE, WORKNO, OPSEQ, RELEASED, PRODUCT, EMPNO)
VALUES ('2016-06-16', '12345', 60, '10', '5454ABC', NULL);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmpnoProblem] (DATE, WORKNO, OPSEQ, RELEASED, PRODUCT, EMPNO)
VALUES ('2016-06-16', '12345', 70, '10', '5454ABC', '698');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmpnoProblem] (DATE, WORKNO, OPSEQ, RELEASED, PRODUCT, EMPNO)
VALUES ('2016-06-16', '12345', 80, '10', '5454ABC', NULL);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmpnoProblem] (DATE, WORKNO, OPSEQ, RELEASED, PRODUCT, EMPNO)
VALUES ('2016-06-16', '12345', 90, '10', '5454ABC', NULL);
```

I need to populate the EMPNO column.

When 3 columns are the same: WORKNO, RELEASED, PRODUCT, I'm dealing with an individual grouping and my dataset is made up of these groupings.

Within this grouping, if an EMPNO is null then firstly it needs to be populated by the next EMPNO down which isn't null (this may be several entries down). The next EMPNO down is determined by OPSEQ number. If there is no EMPNO which isn't null further down in the grouping (such as the two null entries at the end), then it needs to be populated by the last EMPNO above it which isn't null.

The table should look like:

[image]

Apologies for a lack of code attempts on my end. I'm not sure where to start with this one. Any pointers at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of sql-server?

Comment: You have OPSEQ 50 coded as 698 but according to your requirements it will be set to 345.  You need to fine tune your requirements a bit.  This should be easy to accomplish if you can work out that detail.

Comment: hey Joe, no it should be 698 as I'm looking for the next EMPNO down, not the one above.

Comment: The next number down from 50 is null, you stated in that case use the one above.  You must mean any row in the group after instead of the next one.

Comment: Sorry, I will edit the question to be clearer. I mean to say incase there is no EMPNO at any level below a null value - the two nulls at the end for example, look above to the last entry which was not null. In all other cases look down for the next EMPNO entry which is not null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve this. One is with APPLY.

```
select 
    a.*,
    COALESCE(a.EMPNO,next_NONEMPTY_EMPNO.EMPNO,prev_NONEMPTY_EMPNO.EMPNO) EMPNO_Fixed
from #EmpnoProblem a
OUTER APPLY (
    select TOP 1
        EMPNO
    from #EmpnoProblem b
    where
        EMPNO is not null and
        a.WORKNO = b.WORKNO and
        a.RELEASED = b.RELEASED and
        a.PRODUCT = b.PRODUCT and
        b.OPSEQ > a.OPSEQ
    order by OPSEQ ASC
) next_NONEMPTY_EMPNO
OUTER APPLY (
    select TOP 1
        EMPNO
    from #EmpnoProblem b
    where
        EMPNO is not null and
        a.WORKNO = b.WORKNO and
        a.RELEASED = b.RELEASED and
        a.PRODUCT = b.PRODUCT and
        b.OPSEQ < a.OPSEQ
    order by OPSEQ DESC
) prev_NONEMPTY_EMPNO
```

Comment: how would I do this to make sure it reset every new grouping of WRKNO, PRODUCT, RELEASED? In the data above I am only showing one such grouping.

Comment: @ColinO'Brien Sorry missed that =) just add that as a joining key.. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Below code might be helpful.

**First** update will populate EMPNO using next not null EMPNO

**Second** update will populate remaining EMPNO using previous not null EMPNO

Using two updates in this scenario will reduce IO when compared with use of single query.

```
UPDATE Dest
SET Dest.EMPNO=NewVal.EMPNO
FROM EmpnoProblem AS Dest
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 Src.EMPNO FROM  EmpnoProblem AS Src WHERE Dest.WORKNO=Src.WORKNO AND Dest.RELEASED=Src.RELEASED AND Dest.PRODUCT=Src.PRODUCT AND Dest.OPSEQ<Src.OPSEQ AND Src.EMPNO IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Src.OPSEQ ASC) AS NewVal
WHERE Dest.EMPNO IS NULL;


UPDATE Dest
SET Dest.EMPNO=NewVal.EMPNO
FROM EmpnoProblem AS Dest
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 Src.EMPNO FROM  EmpnoProblem AS Src WHERE Dest.WORKNO=Src.WORKNO AND Dest.RELEASED=Src.RELEASED AND Dest.PRODUCT=Src.PRODUCT AND Dest.OPSEQ>Src.OPSEQ AND Src.EMPNO IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Src.OPSEQ DESC) AS NewVal
WHERE Dest.EMPNO IS NULL;


SELECT *
FROM  dbo.EmpnoProblem
ORDER BY WORKNO,RELEASED,PRODUCT,OPSEQ
```